# ¿Qué ocurre con los «require» en este modelo de datos?

Tags: php, poo

Es un placer saludar a esta distinguida comunidad después de un tiempo de ausencia.

Vengo con una duda sobre este modelo de datos.

Tengo varias clases que se relacionan de una forma jerárquica del siguiente modo:

```
Liturgia
    |
    |........Breviario
                  |
                  |...........Oficio
                  |...........Laudes
                  |...........Tercia
                  |...........Otros...
```

La forma en la que funciona es la siguiente:

1. Se crea una instancia de `Liturgia`
2. Desde `Liturgia` se usa un *getter* para obtener la instancia de `Breviario`
3. Desde `Breviario` se usa un *getter* para obtener las instancias de `Oficio`, `Laudes`  u otros, según se necesite. En este nivel *3*  habrá casos en los que sólo se necesite trabajar con la clase `Oficio` o con la clase `Laudes`, etc.

La clase `Breviario`  se presenta de este modo:

```
class Breviario
{

    private  $oLaudes;
    private  $oOficio;

    public function __construct($mData){
        $this->oLaudes=$mData->laudes;
        $this->oOficio=$mData->oficio;
    }

    public function getLaudes(){
        require MODELS.'Laudes.php';
        return new Laudes($this->oLaudes);
    }
    public function getOficio(){
        require MODELS.'Oficio.php';
        return new Oficio($this->oOficio);
    }
    // .... Otros métodos
}
```

Mi duda es con los `require` en los *getter*  de la clase `Breviario`. Según mi criterio estos archivos se añadirán únicamente cuando se invoque cada *getter*. ¿Estoy en lo cierto?  ¿O los archivos se agregan cuando se crea la instancia de la clase? ¿Hay alguna forma de saber lo que ocurre?

**¿Por qué la duda?** Si al crear la instancia de la clase se hacen los `require` de los diferentes métodos, y me interesa trabajar únicamente con la clase `Oficio`por ejemplo, el modelo estaría mal, **porque estoy requiriendo `Laudes` y las otras clases cuando no voy a hacer uso de ellas**.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de caso de uso, es una clase llamada `OficioActivity`:

```
class OficioActivity
{
    // ... 

    public function show()
    {
        require MODELS.'Liturgia.php';
        $oLiturgia=new LiturgiaGeneral($this->mData);
        $oBreviario=$oLiturgia->getBreviario();
        $oOficio=$oBreviario->getOficio();
        $oSanto=$oLiturgia->getSanto();
        $oInvitatorio=$oOficio->getInvitatorio();
        $oHimno=$oOficio->getHimno();
        $oSalmodia=$oOficio->getSalmodia();
        $oSalmoCompleto=$oSalmodia->getSalmoCompleto();
        $oLecturas=$oOficio->getOficioLecturas();
        $oLecturaBiblica=$oLecturas->getLecturaBiblica();
        $oTeDeum=$oOficio->getTeDeum();
        $oLecturaPatristica=$oLecturas->getLecturaPatristica();
        $oOracion=$oOficio->getOracion();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Mi duda es con los require en los getter de la clase Breviario. Según mi criterio estos archivos se añadirán únicamente cuando se invoque cada getter. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿O los archivos se agregan cuando se crea la instancia de la clase? ¿Hay alguna forma de saber lo que ocurre?

Estas en lo cierto, solo se incluirán los archivos cuando se invoquen a los métodos que incluyen el código que los requiere.

En otras palabras, **`PHP` ejecuta el código solo cuando se lo solicita.**

La forma mas simple y rápida que se me ocurre para validar que funciona como supones es:

- Agregar un `die('[MENSAJE]')` al principio del archivo `Oficio.php`
- Usar cualquier método excepto `getOficio()`

El código no debería fallar, es decir, **no debería aparecer `[MENSAJE]`** (*a no ser que desde algún otro lado este archivo se este incluyendo*).

Comment: Como recomendación, deberías usar `require_once` o en su defecto validar que no exista la clase (`class_exists`) antes de incluirlas.